# Help - Insert into MySQL Database Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to allow users to register with the site I am creating, however the code I am using is not working and I need you're help.

```
$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."'");
```

Database:
[alt text http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/2457/screenshot20100805at001.png](http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/2457/screenshot20100805at001.png)

I only want to store the Username, Password and Email Address at this stage.

Comment: not working? What is the error you get? use mysql_query('.{your query here}.') or die(mysql_error()); to find out

Comment: How exactly is not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: post what happen when you use the above code, errors, anything ? Also make sure to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php so you can filter the data being added to your database instead of falling to the injection abuse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a ) at the end of the query.

```
$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`Username`, `Password`, `EmailAddress`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing bracket in your SQL query. Try this line:

```
$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");
```

Note the ) at the end: "'**)**");